# Is it possible to install Adobe Master Collection CS5.5 into ubuntu without using a Virtual Windows?

Tags: wine, adobe

I recently decided to install ubuntu, i formatted my pc and i installed both Ubuntu and Windows. Since it is hard sometimes to get games to work in ubuntu (specially the new ones) i decided to use Windows mostly for games and ubuntu for work applications, such as programming, the adobe suite and whatnot.

Here's my question: Is there anyway i can use Adobe Master Collection within ubuntu without using virtual mode? I've been searching it all over the internet but i get nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to install it with wine. it has got "garbage" rating. More info : http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20148

Comment: It's still worth a shot though. The rating dates from six months ago; Wine has been updated [numerous times](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wine/files/Source/) since then (I count 12!). Also, the first comment in the AppDB entry you linked to points to a possible workaround.

Comment: related http://askubuntu.com/questions/172221/can-i-use-this-list-of-applications-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the suite with [Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine).

According [an entry from the WineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20148), a 'working installer for the entire CS5 suite or individual products may be created by using the AppDeploy Repackager on a supported platform. The resulting MSI package installs silently and works almost perfectly.'

These claims date from last year, however!
The installation may work without a hitch with the latest version of Wine; or it may not work at all. The best way to find out is to try it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

it is possible, you can try it here [How To Install Adobe Master Collection CS5](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-to-install-adobe-photoshop-cs5-on-linux-with-wine/3510/)

good luck :)